# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: function, graphics, tuples, typeerror, python-3.4

i'm trying make an account and put it in a graphic...I just created a function for do the account,  but i'm getting this message:

```
A[t+1]=A[t]+An*A[t]+An*A[t]*((Tc,Tu[t])-1)+An*A[t]*((V[t]/Vc)-1)-(Am*A[t]+Am*A[t]*(Tu[t]/Tc)-1)+Am*A[t]*((V[t]/Vc)-1)

 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

That's my function:

```
def Temporal(Tu0,A0,V0,Tc,Ac,Vc,Tn,An,Vn,Tm,Am,Vm,Ct,Cv,Tmax):
T=[0]*Tmax;
Tu=[0]*Tmax;
A=[0]*Tmax;
V=[0]*Tmax;
T[0]=Tu0;
A[0]=A0;
V[0]=V0;
t=0;
while t < Tmax-1:
    Tu[t+1]=Tu[t]+Tn*Tu[t]+Tn*Tu[t]*((A[t]/Ac)-1)-(Tm*Tu[t]+Tm*Tu[t]*((Ac/A[t])-1)+Ct*Tu[t])

    A[t+1]=A[t]+An*A[t]+An*A[t]*((Tc,Tu[t])-1)+An*A[t]*((V[t]/Vc)-1)-(Am*A[t]+Am*A[t]*(Tu[t]/Tc)-1)+Am*A[t]*((V[t]/Vc)-1)

    V[t+1]=V[t]+V[t]*Vn+V[t]*Vn*((Ac/A[t])-1)-(Vm*V[t]+V[t]*Vm*((A[t]/Ac)-1)+Cv)

    T[t]=t+1;
    t=t+1;
    return T,Tu,A,V
```

I don't know what to do...Someone has an idea?

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `(Tc,Tu[t])-1`?

Comment: Omfg, it was supposed to be ((Tc/Tu[t]-1)-1), ty bro